# The way to update[ insert ] partial of the un-order list in multiple container div in jquery?

Tags: jquery, insert, replace, element

E.g:

with **only one container div** :

```
<div id="container1">
  <ul>
    <li>I am not part of update </>
    <li> ID fo container 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and when I **adding new one div dynamic**, I want them to be:

```
<div id="container1">
  <ul>
    <li>I am not part of update </>
    <li> ID of container 1</li>
    <li> ID of container 2 was added here </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- container 2 should has both ID of container 1 and 2 -->
<div id="container2">
  <ul>
    <li>I am not part of update </>
    <li> ID of container 1</li>
    <li> ID of container 2 was added here </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It means when I create new `container`, the new created `container ID` should be adding to the `previous containers`.

And another problem is how to update the `ID list of container` when I remove `container`.E.g:

when I remove `container1` , the `ID list container` should be updated to :

```
<div id="container2">
  <ul>
    <li>I am not part of update </>
    <!-- ID of container 1 had been remove -->
    <li> ID of container 2 was added here </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML structure you want is something like this:

```
  <div id="container-list">
    <div id="container1" class="container">
      <ul>
        <li>I am not part of update </>
        <li class="container1"> ID fo container 1</li>
        <li class="container2"> ID fo container 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
```

Adding a new container:

```
var containerId = ... // your next id
$('container-list').append(/* your new container html code */)

// now appending a <li> to each of containers
$('<li>').addClass(containerId).text(containerId).appendTo('div.container ul')
```

Removing a container:

```
var containerId = ... // container to remove
$('#' + containerId).remove() // remove this container
$('li.' + containerId).remove() // and remove any mention about it
```